# Prove an inequality of Prime Numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The problem on which I am currently stuck is,

> Is it true that, $$x+y< \dfrac{p_{\pi(x)}+p_{\pi(y)}+p_{\pi(x)+1}+p_{\pi(y)+1}-2}{2}$$ for all sufficiently large $x$ and $y$, $x+y$ is a prime and $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function?

**My Atempt**

I tried to prove the problem by showing that $$x<\dfrac{p_{\pi(x)}+p_{\pi(x)+1}-1}{2}$$and $$y<\dfrac{p_{\pi(y)}+p_{\pi(y)+1}-1}{2}$$

But I cannot prove or disprove it by any elementary means. Plotting graphs gives me the impression that both inequalities are true for sufficiently large $x$ but the process is very messy.

So, can anyone give a simpler proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality seems extremely unlikely to be true for all large $x$ and $y$.  In particular, it seems likely you can always find large primes $p$ and $q$ such that $p+q-3$ is also prime.  If so, then let $x=p-2$ and $y=q-1$, in which case $p_{\pi(x)+1}=p$ and $p_{\pi(y)+1}=q$.  Noting that $p_{\pi(u)}\le p_{\pi(u)+1}-2$ in general, we have

$$
{p_{\pi(x)}+p_{\pi(y)}+p_{\pi(x)+1}+p_{\pi(y)+1}-2\over2}
\le{(p-2)+(q-2)+p+q-2\over2}=p+q-3=x+y
$$

In particular, if $2p-3$ is prime for infinitely many primes $p$, then the OP's inequality is violated infinitely often.

I'm not aware of any argument for the existence of increasingly large primes $p$ and $q$ with $p+q-3$ also prime that doesn't invoke a conjecture.  If someone can think of one, I hope they'll post it.

Comment: The existence of infinitely many primes $p + q - 3$ follows readily from Green and Tao's "Linear Equations in Primes" (in the language of that paper, the system $(p,q,p+q-3)$ has complexity $1$).  That $p$ and $q$ may be taken arbitrarily large follows from the quantitative estimate which shows there are far too many solutions for either $p$ or $q$ to remain bounded.  I'd guess that such a result is already in reach of earlier methods of Balog or even earlier, Vinogradov.

Comment: @ErickWong, thank you.

Comment: Is there any solution of the inequality for when $x+y+2$ is a prime?

Answer (score 0):

It is not true for infinitely many pairs of $(x,y)$ with both $x,y$ arbitrarily large when we assume the Goldbach Conjecture.

Then, for any odd prime $r$, we have by the GC that $r+3$ can be written as $p_m+p_n$.

Therefore $r=p_m+p_n-3$, so take $x=p_m-1$, $y=p_n-2$.

Then \begin{align*}
p_{\pi(x)}+p_{\pi(y)} &= p_{\pi(p_m-1)}+p_{\pi(p_n-2)} \\ &= p_{\pi(p_m-1)}+p_{\pi(p_n-2)} \\ &= p_{m-1} + p_{n-1} \\ &\leq p_m+p_n-4 \\ &= x+y-1 \end{align*}

On the other hand, $p_{\pi(x)+1}+p_{\pi(y)+1} = x+y+3$.

So:

$$\dfrac{p_{\pi(x)}+p_{\pi(y)}+p_{\pi(x)+1}+p_{\pi(y)+1}-2}{2}\leq x+y$$

Therefore it is, assuming the GC, not true for all sufficiently large $x,y$.

Comment: The OP wants $x+y$ to be a prime.

Comment: @BarryCipra Fixed, under the Goldbach Conjecture, unfortunately.

Comment: wythagoras, I was composing my own answer offline, and didn't see your update until just now.  One problem with invoking Goldbach is that one of the two primes could conceivably always be "small." E.g., it's possible that for all large primes $P$, $P+3$ can be written as $p+q$ only with the smaller prime $p\lt10^{1000000000}$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Such a problem can be fixed by invoking a quantitative of Goldbach: the number of solutions to $p+q = P+3$ with $p < 10^{10000000000}$ is bounded, but a heuristic of Hardy-Littlewood type predicts there should be something like $c P/\log^2 P$ pairs $(p,q)$ which eventually exceeds that bound.

Comment: @ErickWong, thank you again!