# Simultaneous solutions of two inequalities involving prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Are there infinitely many solutions to the following inequalities (with $x\ne y$ and $x+y$ odd),
>
> $$x+y>p_{\pi(x)}+p_{\pi(y)+1}\tag{1}$$and $$x+y>p_{\pi(x)+1}+p_{\pi(y)}\tag{2}$$where $\pi(x)$ denotes the number of primes less than or equal to $x$?

In one of my [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297635/prove-an-inequality-of-prime-numbers) it has been shown that the inequality, $$x+y<\dfrac{p_{\pi(x)}+p_{\pi(y)+1}+p_{\pi(x)+1}+p_{\pi(y)}}{2}$$fails infinitely often. So, one can expect that there *are* simultaneous solutions to $(1)$ and $(2)$ but I can't prove it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Let $p_k\ge p_{k-1}+4$ be any prime following a gap of at least 4 and let
$x=p_k-1,y=p_k-2$. Then
$$
x+y = 2p_k-3 \\
p_{\pi(x)}+p_{\pi(y)+1} = p_{\pi(x)+1}+p_{\pi(y)} = p_k+p_{k-1} \le 2p_k-4
$$